# How to get the data from the website Python

Tags: python, parsing, request

I need to pick up store data from the site https://www.green-market.by/

When the city changes, a post-request is made to https://www.green-market.by/select-city/

I tried to make the same post-request, but it gives an error 500.

I was able to make a get-request, but with a 400 error.

How can I fix that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,ru-RU;q=0.7',
           'Content-Length': '15',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
           'Cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.1917694700.1697713017; _ym_uid=1671631216368203443; _ym_d=1697713017; tmr_lvid=721ce302ebfa2fc381e0ba8656e20e57; tmr_lvidTS=1671631216752; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=5j20jXIA4FMkrSig_ZU4TGETjP4; _gid=GA1.2.2125961325.1698045395; _ym_isad=1; _ga=GA1.1.1752787434.1697713017; _ym_visorc=w; tmr_detect=0%7C1698148842875; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlwvdTI1VGZvMHR1UzRxRHk4Y25iMFBRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImxsTENiOVdOUWlLZDFMNGtcL0poeVVKUHV0NVgydHd0NTIzQzc3Q2k2V3EzZzl0Z3RITzhuV1ZHVm5ZTVdPSlB1IiwibWFjIjoiOTdiOGY3NWNlYTM3YmFlZWJlMTI1YTI4NTdmZDdmZTM2N2U2ZDFkNjgwZjZlNWRkNGYxMDEzZTliY2E2M2Y5NiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Imhha1B6c29YODFxSlhWcFQ1QlwvYk5RPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkR4XC83ZkpsXC85Mk1SNUE4bHNRMVMyRlcxZ3NQZGRVY3g5S1QrTlk0OENiNlVac0Z1WDdBM0p5U3N0Z212RFdvZCIsIm1hYyI6IjM1ZjEzYTJiZWNmNGVlMGEwNTA4MmNjOTNlZjgzOWVkOTFmNjM2MmUzYjZlNDNjMThlOGE0NDY4YzNlMTBjZDUifQ%3D%3D; _ga_R9H1MPJ25Q=GS1.1.1698146961.6.1.1698149080.9.0.0',
           'Origin': 'https://www.green-market.by',
           'Referer': 'https://www.green-market.by/',
           'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
           'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
           'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
           'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
           'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
           'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Csrf-Token': 'IelNECpIvQExsCA1dUiyXEJ2Wc0NGDVjaZOOkKwz',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
          }

url_green = 'https://www.green-market.by/select-city/'
data_green = {'city': '7', 'type': 'web'}
page_green = requests.get(url_green, headers=headers, params=data_green)
soup_green = BeautifulSoup(page_green.content, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://www.green-market.by/").content, "html.parser")
    token = soup.select_one('[name="_token"]')["value"]

    s.headers.update(
        {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token,
        }
    )

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        s.post(
            "https://www.green-market.by/select-city",
            data={"city": "10", "type": "web"},
        ).content,
        "html.parser",
    )
    print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<li><div class="address-item address-item-active"><div class="ai-title m-b-3">
<i class="ai-marker fa fa-map-marker m-r-3"></i>
<a class="sab-find-address" data-coordinates="[54.044430, 28.072946]" href="#">
ул. А. Лявданского, д.1, г. Смолевичи, Беларусь
</a></div><div class="ai-time f-s-12 light">
8:00-23:00
(без выходных)
Телефоны: <a class="external" href="tel:+375447355657">+375 (44) 735 56 57</a></div></div></li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You really helped me.